# integrate "public final class" into "public class"

Tags: android

So i have public class `GPSTracker extends Activity { .. }` and after that  `public final class GPSTracker implements LocationListener` . the second one i found in a tutorial, the whole location tracking process happens here, but as far as i understand, i need to include `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onCreate` methods in order to make it work. The question is; How do i put these two together?

[here is the full code](http://pastecode.org/index.php/view/49487690), so that you can analyze better.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cou can combine them as following:

```
public class GPSTracker extends Activity implements LocationListener {
}
```

and put all your code of both classes into this one. The `onCreatOptionsMenu` is only necessary if you're using a menu. The `onCreate` should be used because your GPSTracker class is an Activity.

Comment: Thank you. I solved my issue. GPSTracker is the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can not have two public classes in same file but you may include another public class within one.
    
    `public class A{
        public class B{
        //some code
        }
    }`

OR

You can have following implementation.

    
    `public class GPSTracker extends Activity implements LocationListener{}`